# Ruby Block in connect / Open SSL issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I have a sudden issue with my ruby app.

I am receiving an error that says:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError occurred in main#home_page:
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect
```

Any idea what is going on?
Thanks!

---

```
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `block in connect'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:800:in `connect'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in request_with_newrelic_trace'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent.rb:400:in `disable_all_tracing'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:26:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:41:in `trace_http_request'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.7.1.188/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:23:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mixpanel-ruby-1.2.0/lib/mixpanel-ruby/consumer.rb:94:in `send'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mixpanel-ruby-1.2.0/lib/mixpanel-ruby/events.rb:71:in `call'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mixpanel-ruby-1.2.0/lib/mixpanel-ruby/events.rb:71:in `track'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mixpanel-ruby-1.2.0/lib/mixpanel-ruby/tracker.rb:72:in `track'
 app/controllers/main_controller.rb:81:in `home_page'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3
```

Comment: What's on this line? `app/controllers/main_controller.rb:81:in 'home_page'` It's the first mention of your project (as opposed to gems) in the stack trace so is a likely culprit.

Comment: @MaxWilliams hello: it is"  @tracker.track(session[:anonymous_uid] , 'Landing Page Loaded', {" a mixpanel.com tracker

Comment: And this has been working normally up until now?

Comment: yes it has it came all of the sudden

Comment: You'll need to look at what the code is actually doing - can you step through it in your console?  Also, logging is a good strategy.  I've got no idea what `@tracker` is so can't advise any more specifically.